# StaticLayout positioning center of canvas not working like canvas.drawText?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, drawtext, staticlayout

While drawing with usual `drawText` the text is positioning to the center of canvas. But my requirment is to place multiline text, so I've to use StaticLayout, but StaticLayout is not getting placed like `drawText`
Here's what I've tried so far.

```
class TestView : View {

private lateinit var staticLayout: StaticLayout
private lateinit var ststicTextPaint: TextPaint
private lateinit var textPaint: TextPaint
private val helloworld = "Hello world!"

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
  
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
) {
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr,
    defStyleRes
) {
}

override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    setUp(w, h)
}

private fun setUp(w: Int, h: Int) {
    textPaint = TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    textPaint.color = Color.BLUE
    textPaint.textSize = 40f
    textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER

    ststicTextPaint = TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    ststicTextPaint.color = Color.GREEN
    ststicTextPaint.textSize = 40f
  //  textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER

    staticLayout = StaticLayout(
        helloworld,
        ststicTextPaint,
        w,
        Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
        0f,
        0f,
        false
    )
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    //Just drawn a rect with cross-hair to know the relative position
    val rect = Rect(0, 0, width, height)
    val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.color = Color.RED
    paint.strokeWidth = 5f
    canvas?.drawRect(rect, paint)
    canvas?.drawLine((width/2).toFloat(), 0F, (width/2).toFloat(), height.toFloat(),paint)
    canvas?.drawLine(0F, (height/2).toFloat(),width.toFloat(), (height/2).toFloat(),paint)

    canvas?.drawText(helloworld, (width / 2).toFloat(), (height / 2).toFloat(), textPaint)
    //   canvas?.drawText(helloworld, (width / 2).toFloat(), (height / 2).toFloat(), textPaint)
    staticLayout.draw(canvas, (width / 2).toFloat(), (height / 2).toFloat())
}

fun StaticLayout.draw(canvas: Canvas?, x: Float, y: Float) {
    canvas?.withTranslation(x, y) {
        draw(canvas)
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting with both
[image]
The blue one is done using normal `drawText` and the Green one is using `StaticLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue guys. It was because i was ignoring the width of the StaticLayout text's width while placing it to the centre.

Here I'm giving the StaticLayout the entire width of the View.

```
    staticLayout = StaticLayout(
        "Hello world is helloworld",
        ststicTextPaint,
        w,
        Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
        1f,
        0f,
        false
    )
```

While drawing the view

```
staticLayout.draw(canvas, ((width / 2)-staticLayout.width/2).toFloat(), (height / 2).toFloat())
```

I substracted the half of the width of the `StaticLayout width so that it'll place in the exact centre.
[image]

Comment: How to achieve this on `StaticLayout.Builder`?